# Distance to circumference of circle from any point and angle within the circle

Tags: math, language-agnostic, trigonometry

Technically it's a math problem, but I don't understand how to turn it into code.

[image: Illustration]

I have the center C of a circle, its radius r, and points A and B within the circle. I need to find the distance AD, so B is only used for the angle. So this means solving the triangle ACD with angles and sides calculated from 3 points.
In other words, I want to find the distance to the circumference of the circle from any point within the circle, with an angle.

Pseudo-code of what I tried:

```
float dis(float a_x, float a_y, float b_x, float b_y, float c_x, float c_y, float r) {
  float ab_x = a_x - b_x;
  float ab_y = a_y - b_y;

  float ac_x = a_x - c_x;
  float ac_y = a_y - c_y;

  float ab_a = atan(ab_y, ab_x);
  float ac_a = atan(ac_y, ac_x);
  float dc_a = pi - ac_a - ab_a;

  return (sin(dc_a) * r) / sin(ab_a);
}
```

This produced wrong results probably because of more than one mistake.
How does one do it correctly?

I read about it in math exchange, eventually learned that it's a simple triangle, but with programming context I couldn't find questions that answered mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach this as follows:

First, we can translate ("move") the given points such that  has coordinates (0, 0). So we subtract  from both  and . This does not influence the solution. So now we only have  and  as inputs.

Secondly we can scale the problem such that the radius of the circle is 1. This means we divide both  and  by the current radius (by ||).

The line through  and  can be written as  + (−) where  is variable. Let's call =−, and let's normalise  so it has size 1 (Here we must assume that  and  are different points). Then we have the following equations that must be satisfied to determine the value of :

=  +   ( lies on the line through  and ), and
      || = 1     ( lies on the unit circle)

To ease calculations we can replace the second equation with:

||² = 1

Substituting , we get:

| + |² = 1
      ( + )² + ( + )² = 1
      ² + 2 + ²² + ² + 2 + ²² = 1
      ² + ² + 2( + ) + ²(² + ²) = 1
      (² + ²)² + 2( + ) + ² + ² − 1 = 0

Now ² + ² is ||², which we already determined to be 1 when we scaled the problem (If we choose =0, then  =  +  becomes  = , and ||² = ||² = 1). So the above simplifies to:

(² + ²)² + 2( + ) = 0

The line  crosses the circle twice (in general), and when  is zero we have . We want the non-zero  (if there is a second crossing), and so we divide the equation by :

(² + ²) + 2( + ) = 0
       = −2( + )/(² + ²)

Finally, because we scaled the problem to a unit circle, the found value for  needs to be scaled back to the original problem.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
// Utility functions to work with 2D vectors:
function sub(u, v) {
    return [u[0] - v[0], u[1] - v[1]];
}

function mul(u, m) { // Scalar multiplication
    return [m * u[0], m * u[1]];
}

function size(u) {
    return Math.sqrt(u[0] * u[0] + u[1] * u[1]);
}

function norm(u) { // Resize vector to size 1
    return mul(u, 1 / size(u));
}

function solve(a, b, c) {
    // Translate problem to C at (0, 0): this does not influence the result
    a = sub(a, c);
    b = sub(b, c);
    // Scale problem to Unit circle
    const r = size(a);
    a = mul(a, 1/r);
    b = mul(b, 1/r);
    // Define W as the direction vector of the line A-B, with size 1.
    const w = norm(sub(b, a));
    // Solve equation to find m, such that D = A+mW and |D|² is 1, i.e.
    // |A+mW|² = 1, or 
    // (Ax+mWx)²+(Ay+mWy)² = 1, or 
    // (Ax)² + 2mAxWx + m²(Wx)² + (Ay)² + 2mAyWy + m²(Wy)² = 1, or
    // (Ax)²+(Ay)² - 1 + 2m(AxWx+AyWy) + m²((Wx)²+(Wy)²) = 0
    // As (Ax)²+(Ay)² = 1, we can eliminate (Ax)²+(Ay)² - 1.
    // m=0 is a solution. But we want to get the other root. 
    // So divide the equation by m, and solve by m:
    const m = -2 * (a[0] * w[0] + a[1] * w[1]) / (w[0] * w[0] + w[1] * w[1]);
    // Scale the solution back to the original size
    return m * r; // This is a signed number. For distance, take absolute value
}

// Demo 
const dist = solve([3, 5], [6, 6], [5, 10]);
console.log(dist);
```

Here is an interactive version where points  and  are fixed, but  corresponds to where the mouse pointer is. You can then see the distance as you move the mouse pointer, and the corresponding line segement.

```js
// Utility functions to work with 2D vectors:
function sub(a, b) {
    return [a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1]];
}

function add(a, b) {
    return [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]];
}

function mul(a, m) { // Scalar multiplication
    return [m * a[0], m * a[1]];
}

function size(a) {
    return Math.sqrt(a[0] * a[0] + a[1] * a[1]);
}

function norm(a) { // Resize vector to size 1
    return mul(a, 1 / size(a));
}

function solve(a, b, c) {
    // Translate problem to C at (0, 0): this does not influence the result
    a = sub(a, c);
    b = sub(b, c);
    // Scale problem to Unit circle
    const r = size(a);
    a = mul(a, 1/r);
    b = mul(b, 1/r);
    // Define G as the direction vector of the line A-B, with size 1.
    const w = norm(sub(b, a));
    // Solve equation to find m, such that D = A+mW and |D|² is 1, i.e.
    // |A+mW|² = 1, or 
    // (Ax+mWx)²+(Ay+mWy)² = 1, or 
    // (Ax)² + 2mAxWx + m²(Wx)² + (Ay)² + 2mAyWy + m²(Wy)² = 1, or
    // (Ax)²+(Ay)² - 1 + 2m(AxWx+AyWy) + m²((Wx)²+(Wy)²) = 0
    // As (Ax)²+(Ay)² = 1, we can eliminate (Ax)²+(Ay)² - 1.
    // m=0 is a solution. But we want to get the other root. 
    // So divide the equation by m, and solve by m:
    const m = -2 * (a[0] * w[0] + a[1] * w[1]) / (w[0] * w[0] + w[1] * w[1]);
    // Scale the solution back to the original size
    return m * r; // This is a signed number. For distance, take absolute value
}

// I/O handling and actual call of the solve function. 

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const output = document.querySelector("span");

function drawCircle(c, a) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(...c, size(sub(c, a)), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLine(a, d) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(...a);
    ctx.lineTo(...d);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", refresh);

function refresh(e) {
    // For demo we fix points a and c. b is determined by pointer position
    const c = [200,  90];
    const a = [150,  30];
    clear();
    drawCircle(c, a);
    if (!e) return; // No coordinates for b provided.
    // Convert mouse pointer to coordinates for b (relative to the canvas)
    const b = [e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop];
    const dist = solve(a, b, c); // <<<< EXECUTE THE ALGORITHM >>>>
    output.textContent = Math.abs(dist); // Output the result
    // For drawing the line segment, calculate d using a, b and dist
    const d = add(a, mul(norm(sub(b, a)), dist));
    drawLine(a, d);
}
refresh();
```

```html
<canvas height="170" width="500"></canvas>
<div>Size of line segment: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Both answers work but this one made me understand the process a bit better, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you know that 0 is always a solution of the quadratic equation, can't you factor out the variable and get a linear equation?

Comment: @Stef, yes that is possible. I updated the post.

Comment: I'm silently hoping that the linear equation, after scaling back, will be equivalent to `distance = 2 * r * cosine_similarity(AB,AC)` :-)

Comment: It is. The asker had also confirmed the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Al-Kashi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) on triangle ACD, we get:

```
CD² = AC² + AD² - 2 AC AD cos(CAB)
```

We know that `CD = r`, `AC = r`, since C is the centre and A and D are on the circle.

We can calculate `cos(CAB)` using [the Euclidean formula for dot-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), also known as "cosine similarity":

```
cos(CAB) = <AB, AC> / (AB AC)    /* where <AB,AC> is dot-product */
                                 /* and (AB AC) is product of norms */
```

Calling `z = AD` the distance we are looking for, and calling `γ = cos(CAB)` the cosine we've calculated, the equation becomes :

```
r² = r² + z² - 2rγz
```

The r² cancel out, and since z is nonzero, we can simplify it to:

```
z = 2rγ
```

This can become code:

```py
def distance_ad(ax,ay, bx,by, cx,cy, r):
    γ = ((bx-ax)*(cx-ax) + (by-ay)*(cy-ay)) / (r * sqrt((bx-ax)² + (by-ay)²))
    return 2 * r * γ
```

Or if you already have a `cosine_similarity` function in your library:

```py
def distance_ad(ax,ay, bx,by, cz,cy, r):
   γ = cosine_similarity(bx-ax,by-ay, cx-ax,cy-ay)
   return 2 * r * γ
```